# Javascript to find information about visitors

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking

This might be too vague, but I am curious to know, similar to Google Analytics (code) that you implement on your site, a few lines of javascript.

How does it detect all this information?

I would like to create a small javascript inclusion onto a site, but would just like to obtain a few things about the visitor. Is there any documentation on how to set something like this up?

Ideally I would like the JS inclusion to be quite generic, but then send all the data to another server to process...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google doesn't get all that from your website. They get it from their vast database of user information. That is to say, they know who the people are who visit your site before and after they do so because nearly everyone is logged into their Google/Gmail/YouTube accounts when they do. Unfortunately, you don't have access to that data.

Comment: Some basic things you could check: The Referer header, which would (sometimes) tell you if someone was linked from another website, as well as various usage statistics of your own user interface. It's...kind of a big field, so you may be trying to simplify something quite complex. If you have a very good idea of what things you'd like to track it could be made simpler.

Comment: @isherwood yeah I can understand the vastness of Google's circles. Crazy when you think about it. Yeah i'm mostly looking for basic data, not all the information they capture.

Comment: @Katana314 The biggest thing i'm looking for when dealing with the referer etc. How do generate a "generic" javascript to capture that information, and pass it to my processing server.

Comment: @Justin I'm not actually sure the easiest way to do that would be in JavaScript. Your webserver is the first location where that "Referer" header is sent - I wouldn't even know how to retrieve it in the JavaScript. Basically, look up how to do an asynchronous request in your serverside language (be it PHP, Java, or other) and how to get HTTP headers, and then just pass those along. For the clientside stuff, you basically just need to learn the concepts of JSON and AJAX. They're both well-covered by a basic google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the type of data. To get information about users OS/Browser they just look at the `navigator` object. To get click tracking and such they attach events to the `<body>` that tracks clicks and drags and such and then saves the data and reports it back to google.

For more information on how Google Analytics works just google it:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, didn't see that on their site.